# rdb vs key-value store for django functionality

Tags: python-3.x, django, rdbms, non-relational-database

Going through the django documentation, this sentence on [mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) states:

> "In practice you’d probably want to record the interest in a key-value
> store rather than in a relational database..."

Why? Why would one want to record the interest in a key-value store, as opposed to in my postgres db I already have for my django app?

Does this mean use a dictionary and store values on the model? Thats still in my db?

Does it affect performance?